# iOS: Autolayout differences with appliying constraints to subview on iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I have a view controller set up in a storyboard. The view controller's view contains a subview(`UITableView`) with pinned edges to the 4 sides of its parent, essentially making the view fill its parent.

I am adding the view controller's main view as a subview of another view controller's view like this:

```
UIView *overlayView = firstViewController.view;

[overlayView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

UIView *sourceView = secondViewController.view;

[sourceView addSubview:overlayView];


NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:overlayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sourceView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

[sourceView addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sourceView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:overlayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:100];

[sourceView addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:overlayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sourceView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

[sourceView addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:overlayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sourceView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

[sourceView addConstraint:constraint];

[sourceView layoutIfNeeded];
```

I want to have a gap from the right edge of the view to its parent equal to 100 pixels.

Now weirdly enough this works as expected on iOS 8, but fails to do so on iOS 7 and the view is displayed full-screen ignoring the `100` constant set on the trailing constraint. Also, if the view controller's view that is being added has no child views - then it is working as expected. Is  `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` being applied to all the subviews of a view in iOS 7 ? What might be the reason for this ?

**EDIT:**

The issue lies somewhere in the way subviews are being managed by the OS.

[image]

When the Container View is set as a outlet to the `view` property of the view controller, things don't work. If however, I set the Table View as an outlet to the `view` property, the it works. Something weird happens if there is a child view with pinned edges to its superview and then I am adding other constraints to the superview. I dont understand why it works fine on iOS 8 though...

**EDIT 2**

The problem seems to happen only with the `trailing` constraint. If I want to modify the constants of any of the other constraints there are no issues ?!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try interchanging `sourceView` with `overlayView` in your constraint?

```
 `constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sourceView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:overlayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:100];`
```

This essentially means that `sourceView.trailing - 100 = overlayView.trailing;` which is not what you would want.

**Edit 1:**
Is `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`: being applied to all the subviews of a view in iOS 7?

NO. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set only for the views you explicitly call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for.

Comment: Yes, check my edits. Interchanging them seems to be fixing the issue. I don't understand why though. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: As you can read my new answer it will resolve the confusion. Basically what you are doing is 
sourceView.trailing - 100 = overlayView.trailing.
which means that your trailing overlayView is trying to go out of sourceView.

Comment: @pe60t0 Please mark this answer as expected if it answers your question.

Comment: Jarora, while this has certainly helped me, seems that the problem is somewhere else. Please check newest edits. Thanks.